# How to add the URL of an image already uploaded, to Dropzone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I've retrieved the URL of an image which has already been uploaded to a website. How can I programmatically add this image to my Dropzone component and see its preview instantly? I tried the following code but the image was not shown:

```
var mockFile = { name: "image.jpg", size: 12345 };
imgUrl = "http://example.com/image.jpg"
myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile, imgUrl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fire another event: `thumbnail`
I can't check code but it should be something like this:

```
var mockFile = { name: "image.jpg", size: 12345 };
imgUrl = "http://example.com/image.jpg"
myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, imgUrl);
```