# Dropzone "addedfile" is not fired when adding images programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, dropzone.js

I want to add `checkbox` to dropzone images so that I can upload only the selected ones. I am going to add a `checkbox` next to each image when the `addedfile` event is fired.

I am using the following method to [programmatically add images to dropzone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27171958/69537):

```
var mockFile = { name: "image.jpg", size: 12345 };
imgUrl = "http://example.com/image.jpg"
myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, imgUrl);
```

The problem is that the "addedfile" event is not fired for images added this way:

```
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    console.log("file added!"); // this line is never printed
});
```

But if added an image by manually clicking on `dropzone` and selecting a file, the above event would fire. Why is this event not fired in the first case?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. Perhaps the error is within some of the adjacent code? Not sure about Dropzone, but I know typical drag'n'drop functionality requires a lot of `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` for event listeners to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had same issue and found the answer here from @enyo:
https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/209

Basically the addedfile.call is a bit clumsy and you need replace this line by the following:

```
myDropzone.emit("addedfile", file);
```

This way the "addedfile" function is called properly.

Cheers

Answer (score 8):

Don't do what I did and try to listen for the `addedFile` event instead of `addedfile` (d'oh).

Comment: Exactly the issue I was having. A proof that no answer is stupid ;). This made me check the name.

Comment: LOL! Thanks! You saved me!!

Comment: gregdev to the rescue! Same here.

Answer (score 5):

According to dropzone [documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events):
The proper way to trigger `addedfile` event is to call it in the `init` section when you instantiate dropzone.

Example:

```
   Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
      init: function() {
       this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });
      }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

Must call myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile); after declared "addedfile" callback.