# react-dropzone: populate field with image already uploaded to server

Tags: react-native, redux-saga, react-dropzone

I have a form that allows the user to upload several images to a server.  This form also allows the user to edit the form as well depending upon qs parameters.  As additional information, I am using redux-saga with react, just to provide more background.

I am able to upload the image and allow the user to preview the image after they make their selection and before they upload it.  However, upon reviewing the documentation, I do not see a way to populate the react-dropzone field when the user edits the other form items.  I saw a way to do a preview onDrop but not with data coming from the server.  I also found this article on Stackoverflow because am not sure if it could be applied to my case within the redux-saga scenario: [How to add the URL of an image already uploaded, to Dropzone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171958/how-to-add-the-url-of-an-image-already-uploaded-to-dropzone).

Can this be done and if so how can it be achieved?

Comment: Why you need to populate the field initially? [Input type file src is read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763941/fill-input-file-form-with-javascript). I guess ability to see the image for the user is enough for edit screen, no? What else you'd like to achieve?